# Codecov in Fortran via github

Tags: fortran, code-coverage

I've a simple fortran repo that I'm trying to test using fruit for standard unit testing, and testing a complete run by cleaning and recompiling the code, running the code and comparing the output to a text file.

I'm compiling this using the following flags;

```
 -O2 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -ffree-form -fimplicit-none -Wall -Wpedantic -fcheck=all -fPIC
```

The problem is in the most simple file src/hello.f90
[image]

The function ProductCustom is never run, but the compiler doesn't know that as it depends on a runtime variable. So this function is never run, and should be pulling down the coverage (currently 100%) and be noted as "Uncovered".

Can anyone explain how to get this to work please? Full repo can be found here [TestFortranCodeCov](https://github.com/JamesAllsopp/TestFortranCodeCov).